# Standardize data columns in R in subgrups

Tags: r

I'm struggling with standardization of data columns in R in subgroups.

I created the data frame:

```
df<-data.frame(
salesPerson=sample(c('Alan','Bob','Cindy'),20 ,replace=TRUE)
, quater=sample(c('Q1','Q2','Q3'),20 ,replace=TRUE) 
,salesValue=runif(20, 5.0, 7.5)
)
```

I would like to add additional column to the data frame with scaled values of Sales.

To scale all column I can use code:

```
df$salesValueScaled<-scale(df$salesValue)
```

The problem is that I would like to scale sales separably for each combination of columns salesPerson and quater. Sth like:

```
df$salesValueScaled<-scale(df$salesValue, by =c(df$salesPerson,df$quater))
```

I have been searching for this solution on this forum but I couldn't find a solution to this problem.

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(salesPerson, quater) %>% mutate(scaled_Col = scale(salesValue))`?

Comment: @michalk You may want to check out a tutorial on `dplyr` and / or `data.table`.  Both packages do this kind of thing well.

Comment: @Abdou: almost ideal but when there is only one observation in the subset then I got Na.

Comment: You can't scale something that's only one observation. Scaling implies taking ranges but you can't take ranges when you only have one value.

Comment: @michalk Depending on how you want to handle the situation where you only have one value, you could filter out the 1 value observations as in `df %>% group_by(salesPerson, quater) %>% filter(n() > 1) %>% mutate(scaled_Col = scale(salesValue)) %>% ungroup`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` for this:

```
library(dplyr)

new_df <- df %>% group_by(salesPerson, quater) %>% 
  mutate(scaled_Col = scale(salesValue)) %>% 
  ungroup
```

To work around rows that return `NA`s, you can either keep the original values as they are or filter them out before scaling:

Keeping the original values (by keeping scaling only instances where `NROW` is greater than 1):

```
new_df <- df %>% group_by(salesPerson, quater) %>% 
  mutate(scaled_Col = ifelse(NROW(salesValue) > 1, scale(salesValue), salesValue)) %>% 
  ungroup
```

Filtering them out (as suggested by @steveb):

```
new_df <- df %>% group_by(salesPerson, quater) %>% 
  filter(n() > 1) %>% 
  mutate(scaled_Col = scale(salesValue)) %>% 
  ungroup
```

I hope this helps.